# Adding an integer number of new class objects to a list

Tags: python

Am I able to simply do:

```
for i in range(some_integer):
    my_list.append(SomeClass(some_parameter))
```

Or would I need to create a reference to it first, like:

```
for i in range(some_integer):
    new_thing = SomeClass(some_parameter)
    my_list.append(new_thing)
```

Comment: *Am I able to...?*  Seems like the sort of question that can easily be answered via trial-and-error. If your question is more specific, please revise with additional details.

Comment: The reason is because I'm working with a given starter code, and if I trial-and-error I won't know exactly why this is the case.

Comment: Why *what* is the case? Either you *can*, or you *can't*. Trial and error will show you which is possible. So, what is your real question??